# How do I call myself using Facetime?

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, facetime

I have Facetime on my MacBook and Facetime on my iPad.  Of course I also have one Apple ID account.  Sometimes the family uses the iPad while I'm away.  I'd like to be able to call "myself", that is my iPad from my MacBook.  How do I do this?

Comment: I was wondering this myself, it doesn't make sense why you can call any account except your own when you have multiple devices attached to that account.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer - you can either call a phone number (iPhone + FaceTime) or an AppleID (iPod/Mac/iPad + FaceTime) and you can't call another device with the same number.

To call back to your mac (or any other AppleID device) - you'll have to make a second account with a different Apple ID. Similarly - there's no easy way to get the phone number into another device since that gets authenticated over SMS in the background and not user/password for AppleID.

If you are calling from an iPhone - you can call your AppleID devices (they all ring and any one can pick up), but for AppleID based calls - you need to call a different AppleID unless Apple ever changes the current software.

Last clarification - AppleID is just a string but most people use an email address since that is more likely to be unique to one person.

Comment: For clarification, for each Apple device a person owns, one will need a unique Apple ID AND unique email address?

Comment: Not at all. I'll try to edit my answer to be more clear. Comment again if I still haven't hit the mark.

Comment: You don't need another AppleId to be able to call yourself. All you need is another email address or phone number on your device. Just make sure that "You can be reached by Facetime at" section in Facetime setting has different selection in both devices and you are good to go.

Comment: Woah @atulkhatri I will try that!

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Settings app in your iPad. Navigate to Facetime on the left column. Under "You can be reached for video calls at:", click "Add Another Email..." You should be able to call your alternative email address from your MacBook.

Comment: This doesn't work on Mountain Lion as the call aborts as soon as you start to dial. Are you saying they should have two different Apple ID?

Comment: Make sure you uncheck the first email after you add the second one.

Answer (score 2):

OK, just tried it.
I have my iPhone number stored in my Macbook Air FaceTime list, and my primary email stored in my iPhone FaceTime list.
Calling my phone number from the Macbook works fine; calling my email address from my iPhone also works fine.
OS 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

Was able to do so using FaceFime meeting links. I did have different number/emails on devices just in case, just like others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I dont think it is possible with the way Facetime is configured.

Facetime has some sort of reverse dialing mechanism associated with your apple id. That means you need to dial out to a different unique id.

If you create a second apple id for this purpose and associate it with the iPad or the macbook, you should be able to call them when you are away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the email or phone number is the main device and different one each device.

Comment: Are you saying they should have two different Apple ID?

Comment: @James is correct. You don't need different Apple Ids. Have a look at the "You can be reached by Facetime at" section in Facetime settings. All you need to do is to have different selection for each device.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I tried it as well.

[image]

I hope this pic will help you to set up.

[image]. This pic with respect to ios13

Comment: Didn't you just add same image twice?

Comment: This answer is not clear at all.  **How** did you accomplish this?